# How to set space between lines in a rdlc textbox

Tags: textbox, report, rdlc, css

How can we set the space between lines in an rdlc textbox?
Scenario:
The application shall be printing a report to a pre-printed stationary sheet.
One string field of the report is usually having about 400 characters of data (description input by user), which shall be printed in multiple lines.
As a workaround to the problem of not able to set LineHeight property of textbox control in rdlc, I have written a custom code which will insert new line characters into the string (by adding Environment.NewLine) such that the string is splitted into multiple lines. However, I am not able to set the space between each line in the text box. I have tried setting both SpaceAfter and SpaceBefore property. No change :-(
I also tried using VbCrLf and combination of Chr(10) and Chr(13) instead of Environment.NewLine. Did not help... Can you help!!!
I am using VS2010 Premium Edition and Application Target of 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

I added new textboxes for each lines to my report and set position for them with necessary line spacing.
because  Line spacing in textbox properties is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. (It works only between paragraphs, not within a single paragraph where the lines wrap.) Say the font is 12 pt, and I want a little space between paragraphs, but not full double-spacing. I put the extra line between paragraphs, and then I select that empty line and set the font to 6 pt. If I wanted 1.5 spacing, I'd set it to a larger font.